# Get numerical value as a percentage of total of all rows

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, title is a bit dodgy.

I'm having trouble with combining mysql and maths at the moment. Can someone help me, I'm guessing its pretty simple. Sorry if its really easy!

What I want to get is a record as a percentage of the total of all records.

The application is pages in a CMS. They each have a page views field which is incremented for each page view.

I need to get that page's page views as a percentage of the total page views over the whole site.

How would I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select pageviews * 100 / (select sum(pageviews) from table) from table where page_id = 42`

Comment: As easy as that eh? :) Thank you.